# latex and auctex, how to set up latex->dvips->ps2pdf

Tags: auctex

I am using `psfrag` for figures quite often and generating my figures in `eps` format. I would like to set up my AUCTeX to use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` automatically. And at the end view the pdf file from inside Emacs with the help of AUCTeX view button.

I looked into this thread

[How to replace AUCTeX's "LaTeX" command with latex->dvips->ps2pdf chain?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163670/how-to-replace-auctexs-latex-command-with-latex-dvips-ps2pdf-chain)

but I guess the options should be a bit different since I upgraded to the latest version of AUCTeX.

Any ideas on how to enable this and make it my default compile process by using my init file?

EDIT: Here is the updated part from my side. I guess I made quite some progress with the input of Arash in the below answer but there is a very small thing that is not clear. The below code is a minimal example which also uses psfrag and does what I would like to perform if I set `C-c C-t C-p` explicitly after saving this code in a file, say, simple.tex, namely, the steps followed are as follows,

1. Save the below code in a file called simple.tex:

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{psfrag}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}   % With old-style figures and real smallcaps.
> \linespread{1.025}              % Palatino leads a little more leading
> %
> \begin{document}
> \begin{figure}
> \centering
> %
> \psfrag{X}[][]{$x$}
> \psfrag{Y}[][]{$y$}
> \psfrag{Z}[][]{$z$}
> %
> \psfrag{0}[][]{$0$}
> \psfrag{0}[][]{$0$}
> \psfrag{0.6}[][]{$0.65$}
> \psfrag{1.2}[][]{$1.2$}
> \psfrag{0.25}[][cl]{$0.25$}
> \psfrag{0.5}[][cl]{$0.5$}
> % get the image from imagebin: 
> % test.eps location, https://imagebin.ca/v/3x1gUN0CmKbo
> % save it as test.eps
> \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test}
> \end{figure}
> \end{document}
> ```

Extra info: I have this line

(setq-default TeX-master nil)

in my init file as the AUCTeX manual suggests. To ask for the master file for each file that is open

2. If after step 1, I do C-c C-c then emacs asks for the master file, default is to set the above file as master, just typed return
3. After typing return, these 4 new lines are added to the file to show that it is the master file:

> ```
> %%% Local Variables:
> %%% mode: latex
> %%% TeX-master: t
> %%% End:
> ```

and asks to save the file, ok, pressed y and saved it.

Then it jumped to Command (default LaTeX): which is followed by enter. Latex succesfully compiled the document to dvi format.

Now if I perform one more C-c C-c, I am getting

```
Cannot find "dvips and gv" viewer. Select another one in 'TeX-view-program-selection'
```

This was the part that was not working for viewing the output file as a pdf output although I had the following in my init file which were added after performing M-x customize variable for

```
TeX-PDF-mode -> setting it to on
Tex-PDF-from-DVI -> setting it to dvips - ps2pdf under Value Menu
```

And the exact settings added to the init file after these are turned on from inside emacs are as follows:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-PDF-from-DVI "Dvips"))
```

At this point, I can not view the pdf output because it is compiled in the latex mode(just for dvi output, I believe), although the TeX-PDF-mode is set to true(t) above in the init file(which is strange).

After the above error message, as mentioned above, if I explicitly switch to pdf mode with `C-c C-t C-p`, then `C-c C-a` gives me the correct output with all the psfrag substitutions. But I still did not understand why it is not set by default as I open the document since TeX-PDF-mode is set to true.

In the end, I get what I want but I did not totally understand why the file does not open in pdf-mode while "TeX-PDF-mode t" is in the init file.

Comment: Have you actually tried the answers in the question you link to?

Comment: @DaiBowen, yes, not fully performing what I want that is  why I asked. The code given there adds an command option(latex+dvips+ps2pdf) to the list of commands that works fine. But, I am still after how to set the viewer and let it open the resulting pdf file, I still could not accomplish that part.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of AUCTeX, if should be sufficient to customize the variable `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` as described in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dPDF_002dfrom_002dDVI).  Try  <kbd>M-x customize-variable RET TeX-PDF-from-DVI RET</kbd> , click on `Value Menu` and choose `dvips - ps2pdf sequence`, hit `Apply and Save` and you should be done.

---

I'm not sure how your workflow is, as you don't describe it.  Consider this file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
foobar
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-PDF-from-DVI: "Dvipdfmx"
%%% End:
```

When you open this file, the variable `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` is set to `"Dvipdfmx"`.  The idea is that you compile the file with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> which runs `latex` on the file and you hit <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> a second time which then runs `dvipdfmx`.  You can take a shortcut with <kbd>C-c C-a</kbd> which runs both commands subsequently.

Here the relevant part from the manual again:

> User Option: `TeX-PDF-from-DVI`
>
> This option controls if and how to produce a PDF file by converting a DVI file.
>
> When `TeX-PDF-mode` is non-nil, if `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` is non-nil too the document is compiled to DVI instead of PDF. When the document is
>   ready, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> will suggest to run the converter to PDF or an
>   intermediate format.
>
> If non-nil, `TeX-PDF-from-DVI` should be the name of the command, as a string, used to convert the DVI file to PDF or to an intermediate
>   format. Values currently supported are:
>
> - `"Dvips"`: the DVI file is converted to PS with dvips. After successfully running it, ps2pdf will be the default command to convert
>     the PS file to PDF.
> - `"Dvipdfmx"`: the DVI file is converted to PDF with dvipdfmx.
>
> When the PDF file is finally ready, the next suggested command will be to open the viewer.
>
> This option can also be set as a file local variable, in order to use this conversion on a per-document basis.
>
> Recall the whole sequence of <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> commands can be replace by the single <kbd>C-c C-a</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Arash, after the M-x customize part, I do not see a page where there is a Value Menu unfortunately.

Comment: Ok it seems that my version is still 11.87 as a result of C-h v AUCTeX-version, this is what I got, but today, I am sure I upgraded to the latest version, what is the problem then? I am totally confused now

Comment: Another point I just found, I can see that auctex 12.1.0 is installed I can see it in the list of packages with M-x package-list-packages

Comment: I can see under ~/.emacs.d/elpa/ auctex-12.1.0 so it seems that it is installed but the system is using the one from the ubuntu repositories if I am correct, I will wait your reply if you have further comments

Comment: @UmutTabak - It is hard to say what's going wrong, but I suggest you uninstall whatever AUCTeX provided by your distro (Ubuntu?) and install AUCTeX from ELPA which you can access with `M-x list-packages RET`.  Then, try it again.

Comment: Arash, back to the problem again, I uninstalled the Auctex from the ubuntu and left only the elpa version so my version now is correct. I could also set the Value Menu to dvips - ps2pdf sequence but if I compile the document with the latex command I see that only a dvi file was generated in the currect working directory, any ideas why it is still not working?

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstanding in my workflow...

Comment: @UmutTabak - See my updated answer.  If doesn't answer it, you have to be more specific about what you've tried.

Comment: See the detailed overview above, bottom line: I get want I want but did not still understand why the file does not open in pdf mode with TeX-PDF-mode set to t in the init file.